# PL/SQL function while executing throws Out Process Memory Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have PL/SQL function, which is programmed to sort a set of data. This function work fine without any error, when called directly as a PL/SQL Function.

However, when I call this Function Via a Unix Shell Script, even though the script returns a success code and throws an `Out Process Memory Error` and function is actually not executed.

I have verified the DB Index spaces and temp spaces, which are more than 50% free spaces

Comment: Is the `Out Process Memory Error` an Oracle Error Message? I am close to assume that the problem lies not with the PL/SQL Function but with the calling mechanism.

Comment: Since you said, you are doing a sort, can you check `sort_area_size` ? You might also try increasing it. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874044/how-to-sort-area-size-increase/1874188#1874188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is presumably `ORA-04030: out of process memory`.  This means your process is hitting a memory limit. (like, durr).

Why doesn't it hit you when you call the function in a query?  Who can tell?  Perhaps you are sorting different amounts of data?  Perhaps there are different ambient conditions?

This error might indicate you're running out of RAM but alternatively it could mean you're running out of swap (i.e. disk space).  If it is RAM and you have some spare capacity you can increase `pga_aggregate_target`.  If it is swap then you need to get your sysadmin guys on the case.

Comment: A batch job may be running with different linguistic (NLS_LANG / NLS_TERRITORY) settings.